# Using aggregate function in QGIS graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm looking to create five fields of grouped means within 33 shapefiles. I'm using the Graphical Modeler to save me using the Field Calculator 5 x 33 times.

The new fields are the means of the traffic volumes ("AADT") of five modes, grouped by road types ("DESC_TERM") in the shapefiles. These functions work when calculating 'manually':

```
mean( "AADTallc_1" ,  "DESC_TERM" , "AADTallc_1" != 0.0)
mean( "AADTalllgv" ,  "DESC_TERM" , "AADTalllgv" != 0.0)
mean( "AADTTaxi" ,  "DESC_TERM" , "AADTTaxi" != 0.0)
mean( "AADTMotorc" ,  "DESC_TERM" , "AADTMotorc" != 0.0)
mean( "AADTLtBus" ,  "DESC_TERM" , "AADTLtBus" != 0.0)
```

I've created this flow on Graphical Modeler:

[image: Model flow]

Where for LGVs (where the model fails);

[image: LGVs input]

With the failure message "An error occurred while evaluating the calculation string: Cannot use aggregate function in this context":

[image: Failure message]

What could be going wrong?

I tried changing the parameters, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you find any documentation that says that this should work? I'm not sure it's possible to calculate aggregates like this.

Comment: Not in particular, I was following this video for the basic structure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyPW8mzssZE

It works for the first procedure (road_car) but not the second

Comment: What does road_car do? Please include a screenshot

Comment: road_car produces the same output as the LGVs step but for cars, using `mean( "AADTallc_1" ,  "DESC_TERM" , "AADTallc_1" != 0.0)` under Formula.

Comment: Same problem for me with 2.18.16. When i use refactor fields  with 'aggregate' function from processing toolbox , it works. But not in model... Formula is _concatenate( "vote" , "id_ws" , "user" NOT LIKE 'zp%' AND "user" NOT LIKE 'zp%')_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue looks solved.

You should update since 2.18.17 is released or try to install nightly from osgeo4w with the advanced install.

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17300